# Define parameter type as NodeList (or other array-like) that is definitely not empty

Tags: typescript

I have a function that creates a NodeList (also relevant to other array-like objects), and then calls a callback with that list. I know for sure that the list's length is larger than 0, otherwise, the callback isn't called. The function's signature is:

`function foo(arg1: number, callback(result: NodeList) => any)`

The problem is that if I try for example to access the first element in the list (inside the callback), TypeScript complains that it might be `null`, even though I know for sure that it isn't.

Is there a way to define the NodeList parameter in a way that would tell TypeScript that it isn't empty?

Comment: Can you show the actual code and error message you receive? I [cannot reproduce this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo%28arg1%3A%20number%2C%20callback%3A%20%28result%3A%20NodeList%29%20%3D%3E%20any%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callback%28document.querySelectorAll%28'span'%29%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afoo%284%2C%20function%20%28result%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28result%5B0%5D%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%29%3B). Also, do you use any special compiler options?

Comment: The TS compiler may not be able to discern that the list is non-empty.  Can we see the code?